# How to keep track of passwords and avoiding password-reuse

Tags: passwords, privacy, password-management

I have lurked for a time on security websites and similar. I came to wonder, with the number of passwords we have (or websites that need a password) how to manage this.

Since I have well over 400 sites where a password is used, how can I keep track of all the passwords and avoid reuse?

I have a password manager but still have passwords that are used way too many times. Is the best solution to just make 400 different passwords and let the password manager deal with the issue and look them up every time I want to login?

Or is reusing for minor accounts the best alternative in terms of usability?

Comment: I think you missed something in all those sites you've read and the password managers you use. The idea is for the password manager to randomly generate the passwords for you.

Comment: Should you use a password manager? Yes. Should you re-use passwords? No. But you know all that. I think the question you are wanting to ask is about "useability" but you have not defined what that means or what useability issues you are experiencing. Do I have it right?

Comment: @schroeder using random passwords makes them hard to remember. For a site you rarely go to its not a problem but typing a 15 character password everytime with random chars on a phone makes it to say the least not really practical

Comment: why do you need to remember them?

Comment: @schroeder because working on different phones / computers makes it harder and syncing between all of them is probably even worse

Comment: Ok, then we are narrowing in on what you're trying to ask. It's not that you have 400 sites, but that you need to be able to manage passwords across multiple devices. What do you mean by "syncing between all of them is probably even worse"

Comment: Using apps instead of websites allows you to store the app's password without you needing to type it in all the time, and many password managers allow you to sync across all devices and auto-fill passwords for you

Comment: @schroeder it's more about having multiple websites / apps but on different machines. If I go to login on a friend's computer I don't have the password manager there.

Comment: @schroeder so for you the best options is to have different passwords everywhere and just abandoning the idea of remembering them and just trusting the password manager?

Comment: Whoa, logging into your sites while on someone else's machine is a massively risky thing to do! And if you are using a re-used password, your risks skyrocket.

Comment: Here's the thing, you already know the safest things to do.  I'm really not sure what we can tell you except what you already know (and stated in your question): Use a password manager, use unique,random passwords everywhere. If you need to make a variation from the safest path, then you need to consider how to do that safely.

Comment: Oh, and you ***do*** enable 2FA everywhere you can, right?

Comment: @schroeder my concern was mainly about the trade-off on complexity and being practical to remember but I guess not remembering them is probably the safest option, and yes 2FA where I can of course

Comment: Only use random/unique passwords and you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, let the password manager handle it.

You should have your password manager generate a unique password for each site. Don't make them yourself and you won't have to worry about reuse. For sites you currently reuse on, incrementally replace them as you come across them. Many have tools to identify password reuse which can also help you.

Based on your comments, you seem hesitant to commit to all random passwords because you use several different devices. Many password managers offer syncing solutions that work very well. Both Android and iOS support filling in login forms with password manager apps. If manual entry is a sticking point, consider generating [pass*phrases*](https://www.eff.org/dice), which are easier to remember momentarily.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - let your password manager handle all of them.

400 sites is not a lot to have in your password manager - I have many more than that. Most I generated randomly. Some I created on other systems and then transferred them in. But most importantly, I don't worry what they are, because my password manager handles them.

Before I used a password manager, I tried patterns, but they are relatively easily guessed once a couple end up leaked and brute-forced, and yes, I have had the haveIbeenpwned alerts on occasion and had to change things. Trust me, doing that is much worse if you have used any pattern, as you have to change them all!!!

Comment: Thanks I guess it's hard to let go and not remember your own passwords as I did for my whole life but it's probably for the best!

Answer (score -1):

400 sites are a lot, I do not use that much, but I just let pw manager deal with passwords.

However I have some sites that I use frequently and don't want to login everytime in the password manager. For those sites I use a simple method to create easily remember passwords.

It is actually two methods.
I create a whole sentence and the first word usually the name of the site, a funny sentence coming from the function of the site or the title of the site. A whole sentence including some numbers or signs no way to crack, except brute force.

The other method is take a poet and the first letter of every word in a verse gives you a nice hash looking-like password. you can tune it up with numbers or signs.

Comment: "crack" and "brute force" are the same thing

Comment: and what you suggest is nothing like a hash

Comment: The problem with this method is remembering the elements of the pattern when you need to change the password

Comment: true, what you get is just looks like a hash. will correct. nobody said bruteforce is not cracking, what I said is brute force is the only method to crack it.

if you have to change the pass, you can create another sentence or get another poet there are a bunch of them.

Comment: "impossible to crack, except brute force" suggests that those are two different things. But they are the same thing. It's like saying "it's impossible to jump over, except if you leap very far". I think you meant to say that it is very difficult to brute force.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your answer is a little controversial, as most of us agree that password managers are better than memorized passwords. For those who do not want to use a password manager, I guess this may be good advice, but it feels very homebrew (who says this actually gives good quality passwords? It looks random, but did you ever test it? Has anyone ever measured the quality of such passwords?) and seems like a step back in security.

Comment: For those who understand hashes, your method does not produce "hash-looking" passwords. `Poe1qtrn` (Poe "quoth the raven, nevermore!") is nothing like a hash. even if you used a really long poem.